# Rails 3.2.21 / ruby 1.9.3 how can I \u encode unicode chars within a string

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, unicode-escapes

I need to sanitize some text sent to an email service provider (Sendgrid) that does not support unicode in the recipient name unless it is \u escaped.

When the UTF-8 string `s = "Pablö"` how can I "\u escape" any unicode inside the string so I get `"Pabl\u00f6"` ?

Converting to JSON also escapes the quotes (which I don't want):

```
"Pablö".to_json
=> "\"Pabl\\u00f6\""
```

What I'm looking for is something just like .force_encoding('binary') except for Unicode. Inspecting `Encoding.aliases.values.uniq` I don't see anything like 'unicode'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that everything is UTF-8 because we're not cavemen banging rocks together.

`to_json` isn't *escaping* quotes, it is *adding* quotes inside the string (because JSON requires strings to be quoted) and then `inspect` escapes them (and the backslash).

These quotes from `to_json` should always be there so you could just strip them off:

```
"Pablö".to_json[1..-2] # Lots of ways to do this...
=> "Pabl\\u00f6"
```

Keep in mind, however, that the behavior of `to_json` and UTF-8 depends on which JSON library you're using and possibly other things. For example, in my stock Ruby 2.2, the standard JSON library leaves UTF-8 alone; the JSON specification is quite happy with UTF-8 so why bother encoding it? So you might want to do it yourself with something like:

```
s.chars.map { |c| c.ord > 127 ? '\u%.4x' % c.ord : c }.join
```

Anything above 127 is out of ASCII range so that simple [`ord`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-ord) test takes care of anything like `ö`, `ñ`, `µ`, ... You'll want to adjust the `map` block if you need to encode other characters (such as `\n`).

Comment: Those examples all escape the \ (eg "\\u...." instead of "\u....", gsub('\\','\') isn't allowed since the \ is still treated as an escape... anythoughts?

Comment: @jpwynn Are you sure they're being escaped? You're probably just being fooled by `inspect` output, try using `puts` to look at the encoded strings instead.